# rails 3.2 / postgres - how cast SUM() to return an integer not string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Postgres aggregates like SUM(foo) return a string, even if foo is an integer.

How do I cast the sum to an integer so the resulting array of relations contains an integer not a string?

I tried to cast it using ::integer

> Widget.select("SUM(points) as totalpoints::integer, agent, company")

but postgres throws error `PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"`

It seems there should be some way to tell rails - short of iterating through each returned array element - that the SUM of an INT is an INT?

Answer (score 1):

This might just be the ActiveRecord adapter. I'm not entirely sure about that, though. But I think when you go down to the selection-level APIs it just returns strings, because that's what it actually reads back from the database. When you use the higher-level APIs I think it knows how to transform it back into the Ruby types because it's aware of your schema there.

I'm having trouble reproducing your query above, but I did the following:

```
Widget.connection.select_rows("SELECT sum(id) FROM widgets")
```

This returned:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] "887"
    ]
]
```

And if I use a higher-level API:

```
2.0.0-p353 :034 > Widget.sum('id')
D, [2014-06-24T15:34:52.644852 #95176] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  SELECT SUM("widgets."."id") AS sum_id FROM "widgets"
887
```

At this point it's giving me an Integer type in my console.  So I suspect there's nothing wrong with Postgres, but that you may need to convert to native types yourself when you're using ActiveRecord select APIs.

Comment: You're basically right. AR doesn't really understand anything about types from SQL that it doesn't write itself.

Comment: yes, postgres returns string. seems like should be possible to somehow CAST that to an int in the query. Right now I use a .map() to iteratively force it to int, but SUMing ints is such a fundamentally basic operation it seems hard to believe it's not a simple query operation.

Comment: No, you're looking at this the wrong way. When you're using some of the lower-level APIs to communicate your query to postgres, it's effectively like you're typing into a `psql` console. Postgres knows it's an integer, but it's basically just dumping blobs of text the same way you're getting in psql. Rails doesn't parse the SQL you're passing in so it doesn't know what types to expect in response, so it's unable to auto-convert as it usually does. So it's up to you to do that conversion yourself. You can't just CAST in Postgresql; postgres knows it's an integer. Rails doesn't.